# docusaurus autogenerated sidebar displaying category index pages as separate pages instead

Tags: docusaurus

According to the [Category index convention](https://docusaurus.io/docs/sidebar/autogenerated#category-index-convention) docs you should be able to add a category index page for the index within an autogenerated section.

> A category index document is a document following one of those filename conventions:
> Named as index (case-insensitive): docs/Guides/index.md
> Named as README (case-insensitive): docs/Guides/README.mdx
> Same name as parent folder: docs/Guides/Guides.md

This works currently but the category indexes aren't working, so this file structure:

```
foo/
    foo.md
    foo-bar.md
```

is not making the `foo.md` an index page for foo but just another sub page.

It should look like this on the website

```
foo/ <-- `foo.md` gets displayed here as category index
    foo-bar
```

but it's compiling as this

```
foo/
    foo <-- isn't recognized as a category index but another page
    foo-bar
```

What am I doing wrong?

#### Stuff I've tried:

1. using `docs/Guides/index.md` format
2. using `docs/Guides/README.mdx` format
3. using `docs/Guides/Guides.md` format

I would have expected one of these to automatically link one of those pages as a category index page

The `foo.md` also have front matter that I've tried to alter:
`foo.md`:

```
---
title: foo
id: foo
---
```

I've also tried to remove the front matter entirely and it has not worked.

Answer (score 0):

In the sidebars.js file, specify the id of the MD file that you wish to serve as the category index page.
For example:

```js
 module.exports = {
  training: [
    'intro', 
    {
      type: 'category',
      label: 'Category Index Page',
      link:  {
        type: 'doc',
        id: 'category-index-page' // This is the id of the index page.
      },
```